# Angular: Is directive link function obsolete about now?

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, controller, directive, obsolete

Given the latest versions (v1.4+) of the Angular codebase, it is possible to do lots of awesome stuff inside directives using controllers. Eg. actually using a controller, doing controller-as, bind-to-controller etc etc.

It is possible to DI the directive scope, element and attributes into a directive's controller, which leads me to ask the question: "Do I even need the link function anymore?"

Is the only argument still that DOM manipulation should exclusively take place in the link function?

Or could you argue that the link function is becoming obsolete? Will Angular 2 even maintain the notion of a linker function?

Look at the following code, where I perform the exact same thing in either a link function or a controller object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <directive-using-controller some-attr="Tralala.."></directive-using-controller>

    <directive-using-link some-attr="Tralala.."></directive-using-link>
</body>
</html>

<script>
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('directiveUsingController', directiveUsingController)
  .directive('directiveUsingLink', directiveUsingLink);

function directiveUsingController() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h1>Controller directive!</h1>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.on('click', function() {
        alert('Clicked controller directive! ' + $attrs.someAttr);
      });
    }
  };
}

function directiveUsingLink() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h1>Linky directive!</h1>',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        alert('Clicked linky directive! ' + attributes.someAttr);
      });
    }
  };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `link` function is able to access the controller of its parent through `require` and the fourth argument of `link` function. It is very useful for creating interactive directives.

Check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Comment: Ah okey, so the functionality I was missing was that of controller communication. I'm still not too fond of the fact that there's a link function and a controller function, allowing you to do basically the same. But I guess I will have to accept that I can only gain access to other directives controllers in the link function.

But why shouldn't it be possible to do the exact same thing in a directive controller? That is, to get a reference to another 'require'ed directive controller?

Is it solely due to lifecycle issues, and will there still be a need for link function in Angular 2.0?